# Is a function in $L^2$ which second derivative is in $L^2$ in $H^2$?

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, weak-derivatives

Let $\Omega$ be a bounded domain  in $\mathbb{R}^n$ with smooth boundary. 
Assume that $f\in L^2(\Omega)$ and $f^{\prime\prime}\in L^2(\Omega)$.

Does one have $f\in H^2(\Omega)$?

*Useless comments*:

Here I assume that $f^{\prime\prime}$ is a function (the second derivative in the weak sense exists). 
It seems a pretty stupid question since once you have f in $H^2$ something like Ehrling's lemma will control the norm of the gradient by the $L^2$ norm of $f$ and its second derivative. But my point is to show that $f^\prime$ is $L^2$. 
Moreover a function in $H^2$ will implies a boundary trace which is $H^{3/2}$ and it seems unclear to me that it can be satisfyed with only $L^2$ conditons which do not see the boundary at all...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $Q$ be a  maximal dyadic cube such that $2Q\subset \Omega$. Convolving $f$ with a mollifier $\varphi_\epsilon$, we obtain a smooth function $f_\epsilon$ such that $\int_Q f_\epsilon^2$ and $\int_Q |D^2f_\epsilon |^2$ are controlled by $\int_{2Q} f^2$ and $\int_{2Q} |D^2f |^2$   respectively. Use "something like Ehrling's lemma" to control $\int_Q |Df_\epsilon|^2$. Summing over $Q$, get a bound on $H^2$ norm of $f_\epsilon$ independent of $\epsilon$. By weak compactness, there is a weakly $H^2$ convergent sequence $f_{\epsilon_k}$ as $\epsilon_k\to 0$. Let $g$ be its limit.

At the same time, $f_{\epsilon_k}\to f$ in $L^2$. Since

- $L^2$ convergence implies convergence in the sense of distributions;
- weak $H^2$ convergence also implies convergence in the sense of distributions;
- distributional limit is unique

it follows that $g=f$, and thus $f\in H^2$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your nice answer. Is it perfectly clear that  the   bound we get on the  H2 norm of $f_\epsilon$ is   independent of $\epsilon$"?

Answer (score 1):

If you take the cantor distribution function $F(t)$ on $[0,1]$ and integrate this to obtain $f$ on $[0,1]$, then $f''$ exists almost everywhere on $[0,1]$, and $f''=0$ a.e.. That definitely doesn't work on $\mathbb{R}$ because $H^{2}[0,1]$ consists of all twice absolutely continuous functions on $[0,1]$, which $\int F \,dt$ is not.

Comment: I think I get the idea but I believe that your counter example does not fit my hypothesis since $f$ is assume to have a weak derivative which if i am right implies that $f$ is absolutely continuous.

Comment: I didn't read that you were assuming a weak derivative. I thought by "useless comments" you were criticizing something you read. I didn't realize any assumptions in there were part of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This follows easily from Nirenberg's interpolation inequality
$$
\|u'\|_p \leq C \|u\|_{W^{2,r}}^{1/2} \|u\|_q^{1/2}
$$
valid for $\frac{1}{p}=\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{q}+\frac{1}{r} \right)$. See Brezis, *Functional analysis*, page 234. Or the original paper by L. Nirenberg, *On elliptic partial differential equation*, 1959.

Comment: Do not you already need $u$ to be in $H^2$ already in the right hand side?

Comment: Thanks for you answer. However as pointed out by Hui Zhang, the things is that I cannot assume f to be in $H^2$ to use this interpolation.